# ViewContext does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, sitefinity

I have a MVC project. In views,I'm using `ViewContext` to load values from resource file like this.

```
@ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("XyzResources", "MonLabel")
```

I'm getting an error- 
`The name ViewContext does not exit in current context`

Following are the namespace which I have added in the page.

```
@using System.Configuration
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Web.Configuration
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities.Lucene.Net.Documents
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.UI.MVC
```

I don't know why it's giving me that error. If I run the project with error, it displays the page with out any issues. I also get the values from resource file.

But I don't know how to resolve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use ViewContext. In your views you can just access resources like that:

```
@System.Web.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("XyzResources", "MonLabel")
```

Or you can use like that:

```
@HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("XyzResources", "MonLabel")
```

**But Sitefinity has better way to handle localization with resources.**

In Sitefintiy backend you can already manage resource labels. (In `Administration->Labels & Messages`)
Then, in views you can access it like that:

```
@Html.Resource("AmazonSearchServiceTitle", "ProductsResources")
```

You can find more information about resources in Sitefinity in this article: http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-create-custom-resource-classes

Comment: Thank you for providing me the link. I tried to use `@Html.Resource` it gives me Html helper doesnt contain a defnition for resource and best extension method overload localizationhelpers.resource, can you help me this ?

Comment: You need to add using `@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers`

Comment: I did that. It didn't help

Comment: I get the same error like I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: That's strange, i tried it twice in my old SF project and in clean SF project, it's working in both. Can you please check if your project has reference to "Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.dll"

Comment: Yes it does have reference to that .dll, I was also registering the resx file during application start. May be I will use `@httpcontext`.

Comment: You can contact with me by email, which you can find in my profile. I will try to help you to debug this problem

Comment: I will do that now. Thank you :)